# SFMC Query 3rd party API through SSJS not on port 80 or 443

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

Trying to query a 3rd party API through a post request from a SSJS script. However, I get the following error:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed 
because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of 
time, or established connection failed because connected host has 
failed to respond XX.XX.XX.XX:8088 - from System
```

In postman I can query the API successfully in a reasonable time (500ms), well under the SFMC timeout of 30s. However I can't query the API from SFMC. I can get SFMC to query the 3rd party website on port 80 correctly.

I noticed on the following page, it says that the HTTPost fails if it attempts to connect to HTTP to a port that's not 80.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformContentSyndicationHTTPPost.htm

However, I noticed that there's no such restriction on this page:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_httpPost.htm

So I suspect it may have something to do with the port being 8088. Anyone else seen anything like this before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly this is not possible. I discussed this with SFMC developers who received my ticket.

If it's not on port 80 on HTTP or port 443 on HTTPS, both the [HTTPPost](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformContentSyndicationHTTPPost.htm), [HTTP.Post](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_httpPost.htm) and [Script.Util.HttpRequest](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformContentSyndicationScriptUtilHttpRequest.htm) will fail.

I created a cloud page to try all of these, and always the same exception:

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed 
>   because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of 
>   time, or established connection failed because connected host has 
>   failed to respond XX.XX.XX.XX:8088 - from System

I managed to convince the 3rd party to host their API on port 80 over HTTP and it worked; so it looks like definitively the non-standard port was the cause of the exception.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up with your solution and information!